# rspec no examples found

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here's the code:

```
require_relative "simon_says"

describe "simon says" do
  describe "echo" do
    it "should echo hello" do
      echo("hello").should == "hello"
    end

    it "should echo bye" do
      echo("bye").should == "bye"
    end
  end

  describe "shout" do
    it "should shout hello" do
      shout("hello").should == "HELLO"
    end

    it "should shout multiple words" do
      shout("hello world").should == "HELLO WORLD"
    end
  end

  describe "repeat" do
    it "should repeat" do
      repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
    end

    # Wait a second! How can you make the "repeat" method
    # take one *or* two arguments?
    #
    # Hint: *default values*
    it "should repeat a number of times" do
      repeat("hello", 3).should == "hello hello hello"
    end
  end

  describe "start_of_word" do
    it "returns the first letter" do
      start_of_word("hello", 1).should == "h"
    end

    it "returns the first two letters" do
      start_of_word("Bob", 2).should == "Bo"
    end

    it "returns the first several letters" do
      s = "abcdefg"
      start_of_word(s, 1).should == "a"
      start_of_word(s, 2).should == "ab"
      start_of_word(s, 3).should == "abc"
    end
  end

  describe "first_word" do
    it "tells us the first word of 'Hello World' is 'Hello'" do
      first_word("Hello World").should == "Hello"
    end

    it "tells us the first word of 'oh dear' is 'oh'" do
      first_word("oh dear").should == "oh"
    end
  end

  describe "titleize" do
    it "capitalizes a word" do
      titleize("jaws").should == "Jaws"
    end

    it "capitalizes every word (aka title case)" do
      titleize("david copperfield").should == "David Copperfield"
    end

    it "doesn't capitalize 'little words' in a title" do
      titleize("war and peace").should == "War and Peace"
    end

    it "does capitalize 'little words' at the start of a title" do
      titleize("the bridge over the river kwai").should == "The Bridge over the River Kwai"
    end
  end

end
```

But when i run this, it says No examples found.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the name of your file?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. How do you run this (what is the command you type in the terminal)?

Comment: name of this file is simon_says_spec, and I typed in rspec simon_says_spec.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sorry for not seeing this earlier - I hope you kept with it)

that error is when you rspec the wrong file. if you do the lib/simon_says in rspec you'll get the "no examples found" try it with the file in spec.

If you go to terminal and just type rspec (space after c) then drag 03_simon_says_spec.rb  to terminal you'll get the entire path

for example:  rspec /Users/james/mainTestFolder/spec/03_simon_says_spec.rb

and it will find the lib/03_simon_says.rb correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you dragged the file into your terminal and the rspec noticed the file, i suggest you to work on the main system directory such as /Documents folder, what i noticed was that terminal apps sometimes require the whole file path to process unless it's in system directories.